# SQL Server A network-related or instance-specific error

Tags: sql-server

I have a windows service that performs a lot of hits to database. Sometimes the database connection is down and I got exception "A network-related or instance-specific error". I got this behavior on two different networks and database servers. In both cases the windows service and the SQL Server are on two different machines.

Is it a normal behavior that SQL server drop connections when there is a lot of hits?

What are chances?

Comment: SQL Server is actually very good at maintaining high levels of traffic and throughput. Maybe it's your actual network that is getting saturated, not SQL Server.

Comment: Does the client application use connection pooling? Have you inspected all the relevant PerfMon counters to see if there's anything wrong?